# Meteor, move scripts to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to move the script includes to the bottom of the page? If so, how may i accomplish it?

Here is part of the head element with some js includes.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/2cc614b628d110d743e8e0b72c52ea2ce7c90f9d.css?meteor_css_resource=true">

    <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/43f99073f97b9a8a6279cb0eb0f7e5b32dc2b4ab.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof Package === 'undefined' ||
        ! Package.webapp ||
        ! Package.webapp.WebApp ||
        ! Package.webapp.WebApp._isCssLoaded())
        document.location.reload(); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way how to all javascript files from the head before the body closing tag using the inject-initial package (https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/inject-initial)

The following code snippet, when run on the **server**, will move all scripts from the head to the bottom, before the closing `</body>` tag. Except meteors `__meteor_runtime_config` script tag.

```
Inject.rawModHtml('moveScriptsToBottom', function(html) {
    // get all scripts
    var scripts = html.match(/<script type="text\/javascript" src.*"><\/script>\n/g);
    // remove all scripts
    html = html.replace(/<script type="text\/javascript" src.*"><\/script>\n/g, '');
    // add scripts to the bottom
    return html.replace(/<\/body>/, scripts.join('') + '\n</body>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @frozeman! The project is hibernating so I haven't tested it. Anyway it is good to know of this package.

Comment: If you ever want meteor as static assets and a tool where you can also move the script tags where ever you want in the HTML use https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client

Answer (score 0):

Meteor packages all your files into one single big one, all separated with JavaScript closures.

Right now, Meteor prioritizes loading files first in the `/lib` folder, then in an alphabetical manner, and it works recursively. So the first files that get loaded are in the deepest `/lib/lib....` folder in your files (although I don't see a reason why you need anything deeper than 1-2 levels). Meteor also loads `main.*` files **last**.

Now, if you really want Meteor to load your files last, you have to **NOT** put them in a `/lib` folder, and give it a filename that matches `main.*`.

References : http://docs.meteor.com/

> Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories,
>   so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first, and files
>   in the root directory are loaded last.
>
> Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by
>   filename.
>
> After sorting as described above, all files under directories named
>   lib are moved before everything else (preserving their order).
>
> Finally, all files that match main.* are moved after everything else
>   (preserving their order).

Comment: Nice explanation, though its not answering the question. File loading in meteor has nothing to do with how they are served.

If one would move the concatenated scripts to the bottom of the page, one could try using the inject-inital packages rawModHtml method: https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/inject-initial

Answer (score -1):

I've included scripts in the end of the html but before the  but I see you are calling references to google and etc I think those ones should go always in the top of the page cause they have to load before the page display so that ensures that it is available when needed. :)
I'm not very professional about web but I'w working right now with html and js and the scripts I put in the bottom are the ones I use for animations or when I used it in a html element that is completely loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yamulema! I don't know how to 'instruct' meteorjs to place the scripts at them bottom of the page, that's my issue.

Comment: oh well, in that case I cant help I havent worked with meteor js :( sorry